# Set property System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style threw a exception

Tags: c#, wpf

Forgive me I just a newbie in `WPF`.

I got a exception when I was trying to debug my little `WPF` application in the `VS2012`, Please review below screenshot. and I tried to find out what exactly the exception is . But didn't found a way to get more detail message of the exception. Because the code seems break in the first line of `XAML`.

[image]
[image]

I thought It may be caused by bad code in the my Style `DataGridDemoStyle`. But I didn't know what code cause error. Is there any way to see the detail like `InnerException` of the error?

Thanks.

***Update***

After I checked the style code line by line.

I found a style named `DataGridDemoRowStyle` caused the error.I don't know why this style will cause the error. Because If I remove it . The error will gone. Please review below.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridDemoStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <!--<Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="{StaticResource RowBackgroundAlternateBrush}" />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>-->
        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource bearBrush}" />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="ColumnHeaderHeight" Value="50" />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="All" />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="{StaticResource RowBackgroundBrush}" />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="4" />-->
        <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridDemoRowStyle}" />

        <!--<Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="50" />-->
        <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="22" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHorizontalLinesBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" /><!---->

        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DatagridColumnHeaderCustomTemplateStyle}" />
    </Style>
    <!--I don't know why below style will cause the error. If I remove it . the error will gone.-->
    <Style x:Key="DataGridDemoRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="2" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RowBackgroundAlternationIndex2Brush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="3">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RowBackgroundAlternationIndex3Brush}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Is there something wrong with the `DataGridDemoRowStyle` style ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the reason.

If I put sub styles after the main style `DataGridDemoStyle`. WPF will not be able to find and load them. So I have to put all the dependence style before the `DataGridDemoStyle`.

The right way :

```
<Style x:Key="substyle1" >..</Style>
<Style x:Key="substyle2" >..</Style>
..
<Style x:Key="substylen" >..</Style>
<Style x:Key="mainstyle" >
   ...
   <Setter Property="xxx" Value="{StaticResource substylen}" />
</style>
```

PS: It seems complied line by line for the XAML. everything dependence should be ready before the specified line of code compilation. I didn't know if it is right. Please help to review.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks your help to review my question. Have nice day.:)